# Bound for truncation error of continued fraction for $E_1(z)$

Tags: cv.complex-variables, special-functions, continued-fractions

Let $z \in \mathbb C \setminus(-\infty,0)$.  It is known that
$$E_1(z) = \cfrac{e^{-z}}{z+\cfrac{1}{1+\cfrac{1}{z+\cfrac{2}{1+\cfrac{2}{z+\cfrac{3}{1+\cdots}}}}}}.$$
For example, see http://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/ExpIntegralE/10/

Let $f_n(z)$ be the $n$th convergent (or "approximant") of the continued fraction above.  Is there a good "a posteriori" upper bound (in the sense of William B. Jones and R. I. Snell, *[Truncation Error Bounds for Continued Fractions](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2949746)*, SIAM Journal on Numerical Analysis
**6** No. 2 (1969), pp. 210-221) for the truncation error $|E_1(z)-f_n(z)|$?  In other words, if one writes
$$|E_1(z)-f_n(z)| = K_n(z)|f_n(z)-f_{n-1}(z)|,$$ where $K_n(z)$ is real and positive, then can one provide a good upper bound for $K_n(z)$?

(Note: I'm happy to assume that the imaginary part of $z$ is as small positive as you like.)

For a related question, see the math.SE question [Formula for the error of the nth convergent of the continued fraction representation of $E_1(x)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2242922/formula-for-the-error-of-the-nth-convergent-of-the-continued-fraction-representa).